# returning the same values for all guests

Tags: python

I am trying to pull performance data from vcenter for each vms. I have the below script. When I try to print out values for each guests, I get the same values for each vms. What I am doing wrong, any ideas?

```
# coding: utf-8

from pysphere import VIServer
from pysphere.resources import VimService_services as VI

HOST="vcenter1.example.com"
USER="user_id"
PASSWORD="passwd123"
#Create an object to work with
server = VIServer()

#Connect to the server
server.connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD)

#Get the list of all VMs (their VMX paths) in the vCenter that are powered on.
vmlist = server.get_registered_vms(status='poweredOn')

#For each path….
for vmpath in vmlist:
#Get the current performance manager object (it changes, so we can’t just instatiate it once)
    pm = server.get_performance_manager()
    #Get an actual VM object from the path
    vm = server.get_vm_by_path(vmpath)
    #Get the managed object reference for the VM, because the performance manager only accepts MoRefs
    mor = vm._mor
    #Get all the counters and their current values for that VM.
    counterValues = pm.get_entity_counters(mor)
    #Do some quick math on the values.
    #They come to us in a convienent dictionary form.
    #Values are descrobed here: http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/virtual_disk_counters.html
    if "cpu.usage" in counterValues:
        Cpu_usage=counterValues['cpu.usage']
    else:
        pass
    if "cpu.ready" in counterValues:
        Cpu_ready=counterValues['cpu.ready']
    else:
        pass
    if "mem.granted" in counterValues:
        Memory_total=counterValues['mem.granted']
    else:
        pass
    if "mem.consumed" in counterValues:
        Memory_used=counterValues['mem.consumed']
    else:
        pass
    if "mem.usage" in counterValues:
        Memory_usage=counterValues['mem.usage']
    else:
        pass
    if "mem.vmmemctl" in counterValues:
        Memory_ballooned=counterValues['mem.vmmemctl']
    else:
        pass
    if "mem.swapped" in counterValues:
        Memory_swapped=counterValues['mem.swapped']
    else:
        pass
    if "virtualDisk.totalReadLatency" in counterValues:
        Disk_read_latency=counterValues['virtualDisk.totalReadLatency']
    else:
        pass
    if "virtualDisk.totalWriteLatency" in counterValues:
        Disk_write_latency=counterValues['virtualDisk.totalWriteLatency']
    else:
        pass

    #print them out.
    print "VM Name",vm.get_property('name')
    print "% CPU",Cpu_usage
    print "CPU Ready",Cpu_ready
    print "Total Memory",Memory_total
    print "Total Used",Memory_used
    print "% Memory Used",Memory_usage
    print "Memory Ballooned",Memory_ballooned
    print "Memory Swapped",Memory_swapped
    print "Disk Read Latency",Disk_read_latency
    print "Disk Write Latency",Disk_write_latency
    print "——-"

server.disconnect()
```

This is what I get when I run this script:

```
VM Name Test123
% CPU 2
CPU Ready 12
Total Memory 29
Total Used 98
% Memory Used 24
Memory Ballooned 90
Memory Swapped 70
Disk Read Latency 175
Disk Write Latency 176
——-
VM Name guest1
% CPU 2
CPU Ready 12
Total Memory 29
Total Used 98
% Memory Used 24
Memory Ballooned 90
Memory Swapped 70
Disk Read Latency 175
Disk Write Latency 176
——-
VM Name guest1
% CPU 2
CPU Ready 12
Total Memory 29
Total Used 98
% Memory Used 24
Memory Ballooned 90
Memory Swapped 70
Disk Read Latency 175
Disk Write Latency 176
——-
VM Name guest22
% CPU 2
CPU Ready 12
Total Memory 29
Total Used 98
% Memory Used 24
Memory Ballooned 90
Memory Swapped 70
Disk Read Latency 175
Disk Write Latency 176
——-
```

Since it was returning the same data for each vm, I went ahead and print out the counter values as this:

```
server = VIServer()

#Connect to the server
server.connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD)

#Get the list of all VMs (their VMX paths) in the vCenter that are powered on.
vmlist = server.get_registered_vms(status='poweredOn')

#For each path….
for vmpath in vmlist:
#Get the current performance manager object (it changes, so we can’t just instatiate it once)
    pm = server.get_performance_manager()
    #Get an actual VM object from the path
    vm = server.get_vm_by_path(vmpath)
    #Get the managed object reference for the VM, because the performance manager only accepts MoRefs
    mor = vm._mor
    #Get all the counters and their current values for that VM.
    counterValues = pm.get_entity_counters(mor)
    print counterValues

server.disconnect()
```

Performance values for each vms seems to be the same:

```
{'mem.latency': 362, 'virtualDisk.write': 174, 'virtualDisk.numberReadAveraged': 171, 'mem.vmmemctltarget': 94, 'mem.compressionRate': 106, 'cpu.wait': 11, 'mem.overheadTouched': 368, 'mem.llSwapOutRate': 367, 'mem.active': 33, 'mem.vmmemctl': 90, 'mem.shared': 37, 'mem.zero': 41, 'rescpu.runpk1': 441, 'rescpu.actpk5': 436, 'disk.maxTotalLatency': 133, 'rescpu.runpk5': 443, 'rescpu.actpk1': 433, 'virtualDisk.readOIO': 313, 'sys.uptime': 155, 'mem.llSwapUsed': 369, 'virtualDisk.largeSeeks': 463, 'rescpu.runav15': 440, 'cpu.ready': 12, 'rescpu.actav1': 432, 'rescpu.runpk15': 445, 'mem.swapinRate': 85, 'power.power': 157, 'mem.usage': 24, 'mem.compressed': 105, 'rescpu.maxLimited15': 446, 'cpu.maxlimited': 342, 'mem.granted': 29, 'rescpu.runav5': 437, 'virtualDisk.numberWriteAveraged': 172, 'virtualDisk.writeLatencyUS': 465, 'cpu.run': 344, 'rescpu.sampleCount': 447, 'cpu.latency': 338, 'mem.swapped': 70, 'virtualDisk.readLatencyUS': 464, 'cpu.costop': 341, 'sys.heartbeat': 405, 'virtualDisk.totalWriteLatency': 176, 'rescpu.actav15': 438, 'rescpu.runav1': 434, 'datastore.maxTotalLatency': 184, 'rescpu.actav5': 435, 'cpu.demand': 340, 'mem.zipped': 360, 'mem.decompressionRate': 107, 'virtualDisk.totalReadLatency': 175, 'mem.zipSaved': 361, 'virtualDisk.writeIOSize': 460, 'virtualDisk.mediumSeeks': 462, 'mem.overheadMax': 358, 'mem.swapout': 350, 'mem.entitlement': 363, 'rescpu.samplePeriod': 448, 'virtualDisk.readIOSize': 459, 'cpu.idle': 13, 'virtualDisk.writeLoadMetric': 316, 'mem.consumed': 98, 'mem.overhead': 102, 'cpu.entitlement': 339, 'cpu.swapwait': 328, 'mem.activewrite': 357, 'mem.swapin': 346, 'power.energy': 159, 'virtualDisk.writeOIO': 314, 'cpu.system': 10, 'rescpu.maxLimited1': 442, 'cpu.usagemhz': 6, 'cpu.usage': 2, 'virtualDisk.smallSeeks': 461, 'mem.swaptarget': 74, 'rescpu.actpk15': 439, 'mem.swapoutRate': 86, 'virtualDisk.read': 173, 'rescpu.maxLimited5': 444, 'virtualDisk.readLoadMetric': 315, 'cpu.used': 14, 'sys.osUptime': 430, 'cpu.overlap': 343, 'mem.llSwapInRate': 366}

{'net.droppedRx': 394, 'mem.llSwapUsed': 369, 'rescpu.runav15': 440, 'cpu.usage': 2, 'mem.usage': 24, 'rescpu.maxLimited15': 446, 'rescpu.sampleCount': 447, 'cpu.costop': 341, 'datastore.numberWriteAveraged': 179, 'mem.swapout': 350, 'rescpu.samplePeriod': 448, 'cpu.idle': 13, 'mem.consumed': 98, 'net.broadcastTx': 399, 'net.droppedTx': 395, 'datastore.totalWriteLatency': 183, 'mem.swaptarget': 74, 'rescpu.actpk15': 439, 'cpu.overlap': 343, 'mem.vmmemctl': 90, 'net.packetsTx': 147, 'mem.overheadTouched': 368, 'mem.shared': 37, 'virtualDisk.readOIO': 313, 'rescpu.actpk5': 436, 'mem.compressionRate': 106, 'rescpu.actpk1': 433, 'net.bytesTx': 397, 'net.multicastTx': 401, 'sys.heartbeat': 405, 'cpu.ready': 12, 'net.usage': 143, 'rescpu.actav1': 432, 'rescpu.runpk15': 445, 'mem.swapinRate': 85, 'mem.compressed': 105, 'mem.vmmemctltarget': 94, 'net.received': 148, 'cpu.maxlimited': 342, 'virtualDisk.writeLatencyUS': 465, 'mem.swapped': 70, 'datastore.totalReadLatency': 182, 'net.broadcastRx': 398, 'mem.decompressionRate': 107, 'mem.llSwapInRate': 366, 'datastore.write': 181, 'cpu.swapwait': 328, 'rescpu.maxLimited1': 442, 'virtualDisk.smallSeeks': 461, 'cpu.demand': 340, 'mem.latency': 362, 'virtualDisk.numberReadAveraged': 171, 'cpu.wait': 11, 'mem.llSwapOutRate': 367, 'mem.entitlement': 363, 'net.multicastRx': 400, 'sys.uptime': 155, 'net.bytesRx': 396, 'mem.granted': 29, 'cpu.latency': 338, 'datastore.numberReadAveraged': 178, 'net.transmitted': 149, 'rescpu.runav5': 437, 'virtualDisk.totalWriteLatency': 176, 'rescpu.runav1': 434, 'virtualDisk.numberWriteAveraged': 172, 'mem.zipSaved': 361, 'virtualDisk.largeSeeks': 463, 'net.packetsRx': 146, 'virtualDisk.writeLoadMetric': 316, 'virtualDisk.mediumSeeks': 462, 'power.energy': 159, 'cpu.usagemhz': 6, 'virtualDisk.read': 173, 'rescpu.maxLimited5': 444, 'virtualDisk.readLoadMetric': 315, 'cpu.used': 14, 'sys.osUptime': 430, 'virtualDisk.write': 174, 'disk.maxTotalLatency': 133, 'datastore.read': 180, 'datastore.maxTotalLatency': 184, 'mem.zero': 41, 'rescpu.runpk1': 441, 'rescpu.runpk5': 443, 'virtualDisk.readLatencyUS': 464, 'power.power': 157, 'cpu.run': 344, 'virtualDisk.writeIOSize': 460, 'rescpu.actav15': 438, 'rescpu.actav5': 435, 'mem.zipped': 360, 'virtualDisk.totalReadLatency': 175, 'mem.overheadMax': 358, 'mem.active': 33, 'virtualDisk.readIOSize': 459, 'mem.overhead': 102, 'cpu.entitlement': 339, 'mem.activewrite': 357, 'mem.swapin': 346, 'virtualDisk.writeOIO': 314, 'cpu.system': 10, 'mem.swapoutRate': 86}

{'net.droppedRx': 394, 'mem.llSwapUsed': 369, 'rescpu.runav15': 440, 'cpu.usage': 2, 'mem.usage': 24, 'rescpu.maxLimited15': 446, 'rescpu.sampleCount': 447, 'cpu.costop': 341, 'datastore.numberWriteAveraged': 179, 'mem.swapout': 350, 'rescpu.samplePeriod': 448, 'cpu.idle': 13, 'mem.consumed': 98, 'net.broadcastTx': 399, 'net.droppedTx': 395, 'datastore.totalWriteLatency': 183, 'mem.swaptarget': 74, 'rescpu.actpk15': 439, 'cpu.overlap': 343, 'mem.vmmemctl': 90, 'net.packetsTx': 147, 'mem.overheadTouched': 368, 'mem.shared': 37, 'virtualDisk.readOIO': 313, 'rescpu.actpk5': 436, 'mem.compressionRate': 106, 'rescpu.actpk1': 433, 'net.bytesTx': 397, 'net.multicastTx': 401, 'sys.heartbeat': 405, 'cpu.ready': 12, 'net.usage': 143, 'rescpu.actav1': 432, 'rescpu.runpk15': 445, 'mem.swapinRate': 85, 'mem.compressed': 105, 'mem.vmmemctltarget': 94, 'net.received': 148, 'cpu.maxlimited': 342, 'virtualDisk.writeLatencyUS': 465, 'mem.swapped': 70, 'datastore.totalReadLatency': 182, 'net.broadcastRx': 398, 'mem.decompressionRate': 107, 'mem.llSwapInRate': 366, 'datastore.write': 181, 'cpu.swapwait': 328, 'rescpu.maxLimited1': 442, 'virtualDisk.smallSeeks': 461, 'cpu.demand': 340, 'mem.latency': 362, 'virtualDisk.numberReadAveraged': 171, 'cpu.wait': 11, 'mem.llSwapOutRate': 367, 'mem.entitlement': 363, 'net.multicastRx': 400, 'sys.uptime': 155, 'net.bytesRx': 396, 'mem.granted': 29, 'cpu.latency': 338, 'datastore.numberReadAveraged': 178, 'net.transmitted': 149, 'rescpu.runav5': 437, 'virtualDisk.totalWriteLatency': 176, 'rescpu.runav1': 434, 'virtualDisk.numberWriteAveraged': 172, 'mem.zipSaved': 361, 'virtualDisk.largeSeeks': 463, 'net.packetsRx': 146, 'virtualDisk.writeLoadMetric': 316, 'virtualDisk.mediumSeeks': 462, 'power.energy': 159, 'cpu.usagemhz': 6, 'virtualDisk.read': 173, 'rescpu.maxLimited5': 444, 'virtualDisk.readLoadMetric': 315, 'cpu.used': 14, 'sys.osUptime': 430, 'virtualDisk.write': 174, 'disk.maxTotalLatency': 133, 'datastore.read': 180, 'datastore.maxTotalLatency': 184, 'mem.zero': 41, 'rescpu.runpk1': 441, 'rescpu.runpk5': 443, 'virtualDisk.readLatencyUS': 464, 'power.power': 157, 'cpu.run': 344, 'virtualDisk.writeIOSize': 460, 'rescpu.actav15': 438, 'rescpu.actav5': 435, 'mem.zipped': 360, 'virtualDisk.totalReadLatency': 175, 'mem.overheadMax': 358, 'mem.active': 33, 'virtualDisk.readIOSize': 459, 'mem.overhead': 102, 'cpu.entitlement': 339, 'mem.activewrite': 357, 'mem.swapin': 346, 'virtualDisk.writeOIO': 314, 'cpu.system': 10, 'mem.swapoutRate': 86}

{'net.droppedRx': 394, 'mem.llSwapUsed': 369, 'rescpu.runav15': 440, 'cpu.usage': 2, 'mem.usage': 24, 'rescpu.maxLimited15': 446, 'rescpu.sampleCount': 447, 'cpu.costop': 341, 'datastore.numberWriteAveraged': 179, 'mem.swapout': 350, 'rescpu.samplePeriod': 448, 'cpu.idle': 13, 'mem.consumed': 98, 'net.broadcastTx': 399, 'net.droppedTx': 395, 'datastore.totalWriteLatency': 183, 'mem.swaptarget': 74, 'rescpu.actpk15': 439, 'cpu.overlap': 343, 'mem.vmmemctl': 90, 'net.packetsTx': 147, 'mem.overheadTouched': 368, 'mem.shared': 37, 'virtualDisk.readOIO': 313, 'rescpu.actpk5': 436, 'mem.compressionRate': 106, 'rescpu.actpk1': 433, 'net.bytesTx': 397, 'net.multicastTx': 401, 'sys.heartbeat': 405, 'cpu.ready': 12, 'net.usage': 143, 'rescpu.actav1': 432, 'rescpu.runpk15': 445, 'mem.swapinRate': 85, 'mem.compressed': 105, 'mem.vmmemctltarget': 94, 'net.received': 148, 'cpu.maxlimited': 342, 'virtualDisk.writeLatencyUS': 465, 'mem.swapped': 70, 'datastore.totalReadLatency': 182, 'net.broadcastRx': 398, 'mem.decompressionRate': 107, 'mem.llSwapInRate': 366, 'datastore.write': 181, 'cpu.swapwait': 328, 'rescpu.maxLimited1': 442, 'virtualDisk.smallSeeks': 461, 'cpu.demand': 340, 'mem.latency': 362, 'virtualDisk.numberReadAveraged': 171, 'cpu.wait': 11, 'mem.llSwapOutRate': 367, 'mem.entitlement': 363, 'net.multicastRx': 400, 'sys.uptime': 155, 'net.bytesRx': 396, 'mem.granted': 29, 'cpu.latency': 338, 'datastore.numberReadAveraged': 178, 'net.transmitted': 149, 'rescpu.runav5': 437, 'virtualDisk.totalWriteLatency': 176, 'rescpu.runav1': 434, 'virtualDisk.numberWriteAveraged': 172, 'mem.zipSaved': 361, 'virtualDisk.largeSeeks': 463, 'net.packetsRx': 146, 'virtualDisk.writeLoadMetric': 316, 'virtualDisk.mediumSeeks': 462, 'power.energy': 159, 'cpu.usagemhz': 6, 'virtualDisk.read': 173, 'rescpu.maxLimited5': 444, 'virtualDisk.readLoadMetric': 315, 'cpu.used': 14, 'sys.osUptime': 430, 'virtualDisk.write': 174, 'disk.maxTotalLatency': 133, 'datastore.read': 180, 'datastore.maxTotalLatency': 184, 'mem.zero': 41, 'rescpu.runpk1': 441, 'rescpu.runpk5': 443, 'virtualDisk.readLatencyUS': 464, 'power.power': 157, 'cpu.run': 344, 'virtualDisk.writeIOSize': 460, 'rescpu.actav15': 438, 'rescpu.actav5': 435, 'mem.zipped': 360, 'virtualDisk.totalReadLatency': 175, 'mem.overheadMax': 358, 'mem.active': 33, 'virtualDisk.readIOSize': 459, 'mem.overhead': 102, 'cpu.entitlement': 339, 'mem.activewrite': 357, 'mem.swapin': 346, 'virtualDisk.writeOIO': 314, 'cpu.system': 10, 'mem.swapoutRate': 86}

{'disk.numberWrite': 129, 'mem.vmmemctl': 90, 'mem.vmmemctltarget': 94, 'cpu.wait': 11, 'disk.commands': 380, 'disk.read': 130, 'mem.shared': 37, 'cpu.system': 10, 'mem.zero': 41, 'rescpu.runpk1': 441, 'rescpu.actpk5': 436, 'rescpu.runpk5': 443, 'rescpu.actpk1': 433, 'sys.uptime': 155, 'sys.heartbeat': 156, 'cpu.ready': 12, 'net.usage': 143, 'rescpu.actav1': 432, 'rescpu.runpk15': 445, 'mem.swapinRate': 85, 'cpu.usage': 2, 'mem.usage': 24, 'rescpu.maxLimited15': 446, 'net.received': 148, 'disk.usage': 125, 'mem.granted': 29, 'rescpu.sampleCount': 447, 'mem.swapped': 70, 'disk.write': 131, 'net.transmitted': 149, 'rescpu.runav5': 437, 'rescpu.runav15': 440, 'rescpu.actav15': 438, 'rescpu.runav1': 434, 'rescpu.actav5': 435, 'mem.swapout': 350, 'mem.active': 33, 'rescpu.samplePeriod': 448, 'net.packetsRx': 146, 'mem.consumed': 98, 'net.packetsTx': 147, 'mem.overhead': 102, 'cpu.swapwait': 328, 'disk.numberRead': 128, 'mem.swapin': 346, 'disk.commandsAborted': 134, 'cpu.usagemhz': 6, 'mem.swaptarget': 74, 'rescpu.actpk15': 439, 'mem.swapoutRate': 86, 'rescpu.maxLimited5': 444, 'cpu.used': 14, 'rescpu.maxLimited1': 442, 'disk.busResets': 135}
```

how is this possible?

Comment: Oh my god, you indeed do an `in` check for each element. Why do you ignore the advice of using try/except? You probably get same values because some of the variables values aren't deleted, depending on which `in`-checks were successful and which not. This is quite a horrible implementation.

Comment: @septi, I am not very familiar with python, how would you edit this so that it works?

Comment: You should give it some kind of a structure. Writing a function is definitely a good start and thinking about a data structure for the parameters you obtain.

Comment: You could skip the `in` check entirely and do `Cpu_usage=counterValues.get('cpu.usage', 'not found')`

Comment: You should probably start with Kevins suggestion, this way you'll quickly get more information about what's going on.

Comment: What @Kevin says (`.get` with a default value) plus a clean loop over a list like `['Cpu_usage', 'Cpu_ready', ...]` should be way cleaner. You could also print the value right when you get it and not store it in a variable.

Comment: @Dettorer, I got rid of the for vmpath in vmlist: loop, now I get this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "perf.py", line 23, in <module>
    vm = server.get_vm_by_path(vmpath)
NameError: name 'vmpath' is not defined
not sure what is going on here? I need to pull performance data for each vm.

Comment: @user1471980 This one sounds like a simple error (indentation or something), but we cannot help you without the code, you can update the question to show it.

Comment: @Dettorer, I've update the initial post

Comment: (Do you still have the `NameError` exception? It seems fixed). Did you check that the values in `vmlist` was correct?

Comment: @Dettorer, I am getting the same value for every guests, for example, cpu usage is the same for each vm. How is that possible. I may be doing something wrong?

Comment: @user1471980 I see that but did you check that the list you're using (`vmlist`) has correct values? From what I see it could be that `vmlist` contains the same path multiple times.

Comment: @Dettorer, the paths for each vm is different, as seen here: for vmpath in vmlist:
    print vmpath
    machine_name, parameters = get_parameters(vmpath)
    print_parameters(machine_name, parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You could clean up the code and it will probably fix your bug. If not, you have a better starting position to debug…

```
from pysphere import VIServer
from pysphere.resources import VimService_services as VI

HOST="vcenter1.example.com"
USER="user_id"
PASSWORD="passwd123"

PARAMETER_LIST = {'cpu.usage': 'CPU usage',
                  'cpu.ready': 'CPU ready',
                  'mem.granted': 'Total memory'} # etc.


def get_parameters(vmpath):
    """Obtain machine name and parameters for a given vm"""
    pm = server.get_performance_manager()
    vm = server.get_vm_by_path(vmpath)
    mor = vm._mor
    parameters = pm.get_entity_counters(mor)
    return vm.get_property('name'), parameters


def print_parameters(machine_name, parameters):
    """Pretty print the parameters for a machine"""
    print(machine_name)
    for parameter, description in PARAMETER_LIST.items():
        parameter_value = parameters.get(parameter, 'N/A')
        print("{0}: {1}".format(description, parameter_value))
    print('-'*5)


server = VIServer()
server.connect(HOST,USER,PASSWORD)

vmlist = server.get_registered_vms(status='poweredOn')

for vmpath in vmlist:
    print("Asking machine with vmpath '{0}'".format(vmpath))
    machine_name, parameters = get_parameters(vmpath)
    print_parameters(machine_name, parameters)

server.disconnect()
```

Comment: I still get the same values for each guests:Test
CPU usage: 2
CPU ready: 12
Total memory: 29
-----
Test1
CPU usage: 2
CPU ready: 12
Total memory: 29
-----
Test2
CPU usage: 2
CPU ready: 12
Total memory: 29
-----
Test3
CPU usage: 2
CPU ready: 12
Total memory: 29

Comment: Then start adding some debug stuff, like printing out the `vmpath` for example.

Comment: I added print vmpath in the for loop, each path is different.

Comment: Then the problem is in `pm.get_entity_counters`. Which obviously always returns the same values.

Comment: Is there a possibility that same values are actually the same on all virtual machines? ;-)

Comment: I just update the post. The values seemed the same for each vms. How is that possible?